# QT5 QWebView linker errors

Tags: qt-creator, linker-errors, qtwebkit, qwebview, qt5

Right now I'm just trying to get 'www.google.com' to load in a webview when a button is pressed.  After I added the webview in the designer the linker starts going crazy.  I'm using QT Creater 2.6.1 with QT5 on Windows 7.  I added the QT += 'webkit stuff' to the .pro file.  I've tried cleaning and rebuilding, still get linker errors.

for some odd reason adding "`#include <QWebView>`" in any file produces a file not found error:  "C:\Users\Scott\Desktop\eCookBook\eCookBook2\cookbook.cpp:3: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QWebView': No such file or directory"

cookbook.h:

```
#ifndef COOKBOOK_H
#define COOKBOOK_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QtWebKit/QWebElement>
#include <QtWebKit/QtWebKit>
#include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebPage>

namespace Ui {
class cookBook;
}

class cookBook : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit cookBook(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~cookBook();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

    void on_textBrowser_anchorClicked(const QUrl &arg1);


private:
    Ui::cookBook *ui;
    //QWebPage page;
};

#endif // COOKBOOK_H
```

cookbook.cpp

```
#include "cookbook.h"
#include "ui_cookbook.h"
//#include <QWebView>
//#include <QtWebKit/QtWebKit>

cookBook::cookBook(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::cookBook)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

cookBook::~cookBook()
{
    delete ui;
}


void cookBook::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->listWidgetTest->insertItem(ui->listWidgetTest->count(), "TEST");

    const QUrl testsite = "www.google.com";
    ui->widget->load(testsite);
    ui->widget->show();

}
```

.pro file

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2013-01-23T14:46:45
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui
QT += webkit
QT += webkit webkitwidgets


greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = eCookBook2
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        cookbook.cpp

HEADERS  += cookbook.h

FORMS    += cookbook.ui
```

compiler output:

```
15:04:58: Running steps for project eCookBook2...
15:04:58: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
15:04:58: Starting: "C:\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
    C:\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
    cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t -Zi -MDd -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2 -DQT_OPENGL_ES_2_ANGLE -I"..\..\..\..\..\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include" -I"..\..\..\..\..\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtWidgets" -I"..\..\..\..\..\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\..\..\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\include\QtCore" -I"debug" -I"." -I"." -I"..\..\..\..\..\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\5.0.0\msvc2010\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010" -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\Scott\AppData\Local\Temp\cookbook.obj.5244.0.jom
cookbook.cpp
..\eCookBook2\cookbook.cpp(34) : warning C4100: 'arg1' : unreferenced formal parameter
    echo 1 /* CREATEPROCESS_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID */ 24 /* RT_MANIFEST */ "debug\\eCookBook2.exe.embed.manifest">debug\eCookBook2.exe_manifest.rc
    if not exist debug\eCookBook2.exe del debug\eCookBook2.exe.embed.manifest>NUL 2>&1
    if exist debug\eCookBook2.exe.embed.manifest copy /Y debug\eCookBook2.exe.embed.manifest debug\eCookBook2.exe_manifest.bak
    link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:debug\eCookBook2.exe.embed.manifest /OUT:debug\eCookBook2.exe @C:\Users\Scott\AppData\Local\Temp\eCookBook2.exe.5244.2012.jom
cookbook.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall QWebView::QWebView(class QWidget *)" (__imp_??0QWebView@@QAE@PAVQWidget@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall Ui_cookBook::setupUi(class QMainWindow *)" (?setupUi@Ui_cookBook@@QAEXPAVQMainWindow@@@Z)
cookbook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __thiscall QWebView::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@QWebView@@UBEPBUQMetaObject@@XZ)
cookbook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __thiscall QWebView::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@QWebView@@UAEPAXPBD@Z)
cookbook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __thiscall QWebView::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QWebView@@UAEHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPAPAX@Z)
cookbook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall QWebView::event(class QEvent *)" (?event@QWebView@@UAE_NPAVQEvent@@@Z)
cookbook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class QSize __thiscall QWebView::sizeHint(void)const " (?sizeHint@QWebView@@UBE?AVQSize@@XZ)
cookbook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWebView::mousePressEvent(class QMouseEvent *)" (?mousePressEvent@QWebView@@MAEXPAVQMouseEvent@@@Z)
cookbook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWebView::mouseReleaseEvent(class QMouseEvent *)" (?mouseReleaseEvent@QWebView@@MAEXPAVQMouseEvent@@@Z)
cookbook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWebView::mouseDoubleClickEvent(class QMouseEvent *)" (?mouseDoubleClickEvent@QWebView@@MAEXPAVQMouseEvent@@@Z)
cookbook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWebView::mouseMoveEvent(class QMouseEvent *)" (?mouseMoveEvent@QWebView@@MAEXPAVQMouseEvent@@@Z)
cookbook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWebView::wheelEvent(class QWheelEvent *)" (?wheelEvent@QWebView@@MAEXPAVQWheelEvent@@@Z)
cookbook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWebView::keyPressEvent(class QKeyEvent *)" (?keyPressEvent@QWebView@@MAEXPAVQKeyEvent@@@Z)
cookbook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWebView::keyReleaseEvent(class QKeyEvent *)" (?keyReleaseEvent@QWebView@@MAEXPAVQKeyEvent@@@Z)
cookbook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWebView::focusInEvent(class QFocusEvent *)" (?focusInEvent@QWebView@@MAEXPAVQFocusEvent@@@Z)
cookbook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWebView::focusOutEvent(class QFocusEvent *)" (?focusOutEvent@QWebView@@MAEXPAVQFocusEvent@@@Z)
cookbook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWebView::paintEvent(class QPaintEvent *)" (?paintEvent@QWebView@@MAEXPAVQPaintEvent@@@Z)
cookbook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWebView::resizeEvent(class QResizeEvent *)" (?resizeEvent@QWebView@@MAEXPAVQResizeEvent@@@Z)
cookbook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWebView::contextMenuEvent(class QContextMenuEvent *)" (?contextMenuEvent@QWebView@@MAEXPAVQContextMenuEvent@@@Z)
cookbook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWebView::dragEnterEvent(class QDragEnterEvent *)" (?dragEnterEvent@QWebView@@MAEXPAVQDragEnterEvent@@@Z)
cookbook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWebView::dragMoveEvent(class QDragMoveEvent *)" (?dragMoveEvent@QWebView@@MAEXPAVQDragMoveEvent@@@Z)
cookbook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWebView::dragLeaveEvent(class QDragLeaveEvent *)" (?dragLeaveEvent@QWebView@@MAEXPAVQDragLeaveEvent@@@Z)
cookbook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWebView::dropEvent(class QDropEvent *)" (?dropEvent@QWebView@@MAEXPAVQDropEvent@@@Z)
cookbook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWebView::changeEvent(class QEvent *)" (?changeEvent@QWebView@@MAEXPAVQEvent@@@Z)
cookbook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual void __thiscall QWebView::inputMethodEvent(class QInputMethodEvent *)" (?inputMethodEvent@QWebView@@MAEXPAVQInputMethodEvent@@@Z)
cookbook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class QVariant __thiscall QWebView::inputMethodQuery(enum Qt::InputMethodQuery)const " (?inputMethodQuery@QWebView@@UBE?AVQVariant@@W4InputMethodQuery@Qt@@@Z)
cookbook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual bool __thiscall QWebView::focusNextPrevChild(bool)" (?focusNextPrevChild@QWebView@@MAE_N_N@Z)
cookbook.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual class QWebView * __thiscall QWebView::createWindow(enum QWebPage::WebWindowType)" (?createWindow@QWebView@@MAEPAV1@W4WebWindowType@QWebPage@@@Z)
cookbook.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall QWebView::~QWebView(void)" (__imp_??1QWebView@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void * __thiscall QWebView::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GQWebView@@UAEPAXI@Z)
cookbook.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall QWebView::load(class QUrl const &)" (__imp_?load@QWebView@@QAEXABVQUrl@@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall cookBook::on_pushButton_clicked(void)" (?on_pushButton_clicked@cookBook@@AAEXXZ)
debug\eCookBook2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 29 unresolved externals
jom: C:\Users\Scott\Desktop\eCookBook\eCookBook2-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_0_MSVC2010_32bit_SDK-Debug\Makefile.Debug [debug\eCookBook2.exe] Error 1120
jom: C:\Users\Scott\Desktop\eCookBook\eCookBook2-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_0_MSVC2010_32bit_SDK-Debug\Makefile [debug] Error 2
15:05:01: The process "C:\QtCommercial\QtCommercial5.0.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project eCookBook2 (kit: Desktop Qt 5.0.0 MSVC2010 32bit (SDK))
When executing step 'Make'
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First try "Run qmake" (from the "Build" menu in Creator) to regenerate the make files and then re-build. Basically you need "Run qmake" after every modification in the `.pro` file.

Comment: I see, I figured 'clean all' and rebuilding did that...  Good to know I was wrong =). Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

1. Press Ctrl+5 in Creator.
2. Uncheck "Shadow build".
3. Change your `.pro` file line to:

   ```
   QT += core gui network webkit webkitwidgets
   ```
4. Rebuild the project

Answer (score 1):

The same bug fixed. Try to add path to qwebview.h in the include like:
(change "QtWebKitWidgets" to yours)

```
#include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebView.h>
```

instead of just `#include <QWebView.h>`

Try to add it to all files that use QWebView.